# On a Linux EC2 instance, the boto3 Session.get credential() function returns None

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to take manual snapshot of my elasticsearch domain and save it to a S3 bucket. As a part of the process I am trying to register a manual snapshot repository using python client code on Linux ec2 instance. I am using boto3 to get my credentials. But boto3 can not find any credentials and it returns None.

python code:

```
import boto3
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

host = 'elastic-domain'
region = 'us-east-1' # For example, us-west-1
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session(region_name=region).get_credentials()
print(credentials)
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

# Register repository
path = '_snapshot/elastic-repo' # the Elasticsearch API endpoint
url = host + path

payload = {
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "bucket-name",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/specified-role"
  }
}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

When I print credentials in my code, it returns None. I have set my env variables with access_key, secret_key and region_name. Still does not work. What may be the reason?

Comment: Hello! Which region is your EC2 instance in?

Comment: in us-east-1 region

Comment: And does the instance have an IAM role attached? Boto3 will try to load credentials from the instance metadata service which requires an IAM role attached to the instance.

Comment: Yes. I have created an role and connected with the ec2 instance.

Comment: Use the AWS CLI on the instance to obtain credentials - what happens then? I think setting of the env variables is conflicting - ensure you haven't created any credential files and reset any environment variables. Boto3 will automatically use the instance role if there is nothing else overriding it.

Comment: I created an instance from scratch but still same error.

Comment: Are you creating it with any form of IaC? If so can you please share the code? What policies are you attaching to your IAM role? Is it definitely set?